# X-Lite v4 softphone doesn't show up onscreen in Windows 7 (only nonfunctional tray icon)

Tags: windows-7, voip, sip, softphone, xlite

I installed [X-Lite](http://www.counterpath.com/x-lite-download.html) on a 64-bit Win 7 machine. Install seems to go smoothly, then when I launch the application, its splash screen appears, then it goes away, leaving a tray icon with the familiar up-and-down-arrows icon that software has. (I used previous versions of it up until 3 years ago with no problem.) No client window, no nothing. The tray icon is completely useless -- it has no context menu, clicks and double-clicks do nothing, only the name "X-Lite 4" appears as a tooltip when I hover over the tray icon.

All I can do is terminate it from Task Manager, under "End Process".

I get the impression X-Lite actually *is* drawing its window, but in an old GDI fashion that befuddles Win7's funky graphics subsystem. Does that make sense?

**EDIT :** It finally did display its main window -- **some 15 minutes after I launched it!** Maybe it got borked while auto-probing the firewall for its NAT settings?

Comment: Any chance you've tried re-installing it?

Comment: Nah, it worked fine after that. Only the overly long startup delay is intriguing.